# Select custom meta (WPAlchemy) from pages with wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I have read some documentation and comparable questions from others about my issue with wpdb, but I've seen very different answers so I'm slightly confused.

What I'm trying to do is get custom meta data from (eventually) about 250 pages in Wordpress. The wpdb request will be in header.php, and the code has to build an array which will serve as input for a Google Map. The custom meta fields are called _ytF_f_name, _ytF_f_lat and _ytF_f_lng (don't ask me why :-)).

So the final output should be: `[name1,lat1,lng1], [name2,lat2,lng2],` etc.

I'm using a custom table for Wordpress, which has the prefix yt_ (which is defined in wp-config.php). The custom meta is built with WPAlchemy. I have checked the database and the meta data is there (in the postmeta table).

After combining several things, this is what I have now:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$querystr = "SELECT ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta._ytF_f_name, ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta._ytF_f_lat, ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta._ytF_f_lng FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta WHERE post_type='page'";
$vars = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
foreach ($vars as $var) {
echo '[' . $var->_ytF_f_name . ',' . $var->_ytF_f_lat . ',' . $var->_ytF_f_lat . '],';
}
?>
```

The output is blank, so what am I missing here?

Another question related to this is; I've read something about 'prepare' to protect against sql injections.

Is the correct use of the prepare class to change

```
$vars = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
```

into:

```
$vars = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($querystr));
```

?

Answer (score 0):

About your problem, I don't see the error, so verify if you have SQL errors with `$wpdb->show_errors();` before your query (doc [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors)).

The prepare method protects you against SQL injections.
As the [doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) said, it works like the following :

```
 $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
       "INSERT INTO ___
       ( attr1, attr2 )
       VALUES ( %s, %d )",
       $valueOfAttr1,
       $valueOfAttr2
    )
 );
```

Of course, you must change the types and values to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! The error log: `WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'yt_postmeta._ytF_f_name' in 'field list']`. Seems like my code wasn't accurate at all... The column name where _ytF_f_name is in is called 'meta_key'. The value of _ytF_f_name is in the column 'meta_value'. I guess this `postmeta._ytF_f_name` should be `postmeta.meta_key`. And then with _ytF_f_name added somewhere so it gets the values of _ytF_f_name?

Comment: I now have `<?php 
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$querystr = "SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_ytF_f_name'";
echo $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($querystr));
?>` which returns 'Array' instead of the value of _ytF_f_name. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use the `$wpdb->prepare()` method if you don't have values to pass to the query. The `$wpdb->get_col()` returns an Array [doc here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column). If you want a a "single" return, you should use `$wpdb->get_var()` instead. And if you want to see the content of an array, you can use the `var_dump($array);` function !

Comment: Thanks for the tips. There's still a lot of stuff that's not correct in the query. Someone is helping me out at the moment. When I have the final answer I'll post it here!